# What is wrong with this putative proof?

Tags: fake-proofs

So I've spent about an hour trying to figure out what is wrong with this proof. Could somebody clearly explain it to me? I don't need a counterexample. For some reason I was able to figure that out.

Thanks.

**Theorem.** $\;$ Suppose $R$ is a total order on $A$ and $B\subseteq A$. Then every element of $B$ is either the smallest element of $B$ or the largest element of $B$.

*Proof.* $\;$ Suppose $b\in B$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $B$. Since $R$ is a total order, either $bRx$ or $xRb$.

- Case 1. $bRx$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x\in B(bRx)$, so $b$ is the smallest element of $R$.
- Case 2. $xRb$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x\in B(xRb)$. so $b$ is the largest element of $R$.

Thus, $b$ is either smallest element of $B$ or the largest element of $B$. Since $b$ was arbitrary, every element of $B$ is either its smallest element or its largest element.

Comment: Apply the reasoning to some simple example to see where it fails. Let $R$ be a *less-than-or-equal* order on natural numbers, $A=\Bbb N, B=\{1, 3, 5, 19, 20\}, b=19$. It is true, that for each $x\in B$ we have either $x\le 19$ or $19\le x$, but ...does it imply that each $x\in B$ is less than 19? ...or that each is greater than 19?

Comment: @CiaPan: The OP wrote "I don't need a counterexample" -- he's fully aware that the conclusion is not _true_, but could not find out where the putative _proof_ did something invalid.

Comment: I don't give a *counterexample* to the theorem. I give an example on which a specific step of a 'proof' fails. It's OP's turn now to find out, with the help of the example, which step fails (and then: why it fails). He is aware th 'proof' is fallacious, but he doesn't know what. This is how he can find out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The fundamental problem with the proof is that it mixes up two valid proof techniques in an invalid way.

The first of these is **generalization** and goes as follows:

> Let $x$ be arbitary. *Bla bla bla bla bla* and therefore $P(x)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary we have $\forall x\,P(x)$.

The second is **case analysis** and goes like this:

> *Bla bla bla* and therefore $A\lor B$.
>   Case 1. Assume $A$. Then *bla bla bla bla* and therefore $C$.
>   Case 2. Assume $B$. Then *bla bla bla bla* and therefore $C$.
>   Thus we have proved $C$.

The fake proof tries to mix these two motifs, such that the first half of the generalization is *outside* the case analysis, whereas the second half is *inside* the cases (and appears twice). This is not allowed -- and the fundamental *reason* it's not allowed is that it would allow false proofs like this.

One way to express this is that each of the *"bla bla bla"* parts in the proof schemes above must be a **complete self-contained proof** of its conclusion, starting with the assumptions that are in play at that point of the proof.

The fallacious part of your fake proof doesn't satisfy that. It starts with "Let $x$ be arbitrary," so it must be a proof by generalization. However, the *"Bla bla bla bla bla"* that comes before "Since $x$ was arbitary" is *not* a complete proof. It contains the *beginning* of the case analysis motif, but not the end of it. Once we start a case analysis we have to conclude it before we can begin to discharge assumptions made *before* the case analysis started.

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that for arbitary $x$ we have $xRb$ or $bRx$ which can be written formally:
$$\forall x\in B\,\,\, \ \ \ \ \ \  ((xRb) \text{ or }( bRx))$$

and after that he says that :
$$(\forall x\in B \, \, \, \, (xRb)) \text{ or } (\forall x\in B \, \, \, \, (bRx))$$

and this two propositions are not equivalent!

Answer (score 15):

Look at the cases. The first case uses an equivocation. It says simultaneously that $x$ is a specific $x$, so that it can be compared to $b,$ and then says that it is arbitrary, meaning it can be any number. But $x$ cannot both be a specific number and any number. Consider the real numbers, and fix $b=0, x=-1$. This is akin to saying $-1 < 0$, therefore $0$ is the largest real number.

Answer (score 12):

The proof shows that for an arbitrary $x$, either $bRx$ or $xRb$. Therefore $\forall x(xRb\lor bRx)$. So far so good.

But $\forall x(P(x)\lor Q(x))$ is not equivalent to $\forall xP(x)\lor\forall x Q(x)$.

Comment: +1.  Take P(x) equals "the xth coin comes up heads" and Q(x) equals "the xth coin come up tails" to get a real life example.

Comment: Pete, what happens if the coin falls on its side? :-)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that $x$ isn't arbitrary anymore when you assume case 1 or 2. Indeed, once you assume case 1, $x$ belongs to the set $ U =\{k \in B: bRk\}$. Continuing to say that $x$ is arbitrary from here on is akin to affirming $U = B$. Obviously, there is no reason to assume this (because if you did you'd have proven the "theorem" just by assuming its truth). Likewise for case 2.

Answer (score 4):

Yes $x$ is arbitrary, but the same relation $bRx$ does not necessarily hold for all $x$, only one of the two relations holds for any given $x$, that does not imply the same one holds for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that for arbitrary $x$ either $bRx$ or $xRb$.  But, it could be different for different $x$'s.  You might have an $x_1$ so that $x_1Rb$ and an $x_2$ so that $bRx_2$.  Just because one of them is true for a particular arbitrary $x$ doesn't mean the same relation is true for all $x$.